# Feature selection in scikit-learn and multilinear regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn, pandas

I have a process with ~10 features and ~100 responses, and would like to search for models for how those features interact to create various responses. ~100 experiments were run, exploring combinations of values of the features, so it’s a limited training set. I was thinking about doing multilinear regression (possibly exploring quadratic terms) but I'm not sure what's the most elegant/simple way is, in scikit-learn, to explore all possible model parameters to find the most convincing models.

If you have experience with this sort of problem (seems like a standard subset selection problem?) in scikit-learn or statsmodels, please give me some pointers. And please let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not sure I totally understand your notation. Are you trying to say, if you divided number of data points by number of feature you get ~10, i.e., 10 times data than number of features? The big O notation without n in there is really strange..

And what do you mean by $O(10^2)$ "experiments" were run ..., How do you define "experiments"? is it number of predictions?

Without totally understand it, I will still try to answer. I would not recommend Best subset or stage wise feature selection. Try to use all features with [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

This is really a standard problem. Try to search ridge regression. In R glmnet can be used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for chiming in. I removed the confusing notation. Yes, there are 10x more data points than features (alternatively called predictors, or variables, or simply vector X), but there are only about 3 steps along each features direction. By "responses", I meant the outcomes (also "output" or "dependent variable", or simply vector Y), not the data points. There are about ~100 output variables. I'll think about your answer and how to implement regression in this case.

Comment: Clarified the notation. There are about 10 features, 100 output variables, and 100 data points. I'll think about how to implement regularization in this problem.